# How many number of comparisons are required to find an element in an unordered list that is neither maximum nor minimum?

Tags: algorithm

If we have an unordered list has n distinct elements so Now I am confused between Time complexity to be ϴ(n) or ϴ(1) , since in worst case we may end up making n comparisons ,but then if I take 3 elements at a time then I can find the 2nd largest element in ϴ(1) time, so I am confused with these two approaches ,please guide .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

The first approach has a lot of completely useless overhead. Since the list only contains distinct items one of the first three items **must** fulfil the constraint of being neither the largest nor smallest element of the list. All other comparisons are completely useless for the purpose of finding an **arbitrary** element matching the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the first three elements against each other.  (1-2, 1-3, and 2-3: 3 comparisons).

Answer (score -1):

I think it will take n time at worst case and 1 at best case
i think it should take n as average idk